# Grub throws "can't find command `['." when adding conditional to grub.cfg

Tags: bash, grub2

It was my understanding that grub supports a small subset of bash. Their documentation doesn't go into super detail, other than it "supports conditionals", etc.

I am trying to run a simple `if`.

```
grub> if [ "${myvar}" = "fred" ]; then
> echo "test"
> fi
error: can't find command `['.
```

Anybody have an idea? I am using grub2-efi 2.00.

Comment: Does `test` work? (`[` is a--poorly thought-out, IMO--alias for `test`).

Comment: ```test``` command doesn't exist. Maybe that's the problem? Missing module?

Comment: Ah, I see ```test.c``` registers a command for ```[```. That is probably the issue.

Comment: Having never used `grub` and just perusing the manual, is it possible you are in rescue mode (where it appears very few commands are available).

Comment: Usually, `[` is a bash built-in command. In this case, it does not look like this.

Comment: @Cyrus `test` and `[` are normally available as executable programs, though they can also be implemented as shell builtins.

Comment: This doc https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Shell_002dlike-scripting.html states that `[[` and `]]` are reserved words, so try those instead.

Comment: I'm running grub2 on powerpc and getting this error too. I wonder if it's a missing grub module that is preventing additional bash functionality (default is `sh`?)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a grub2 module in order to run `if` tests.

I'm running Gentoo on a PowerPC system (PPC64 G5 machine) and doing a default `grub-mkconfig` then booting from it gives me the error in your question.

Since `bash` has that syntax support, I figured it was simply a grub module that needed to be added (I had been doing work with grub modules recently).
tl;dr: You need to load the appropriate grub module and then the error goes away.

The first step is to find out what modules you have. For me, it's whatever is available in my `/boot/grub/powerpc-ieee1275/` folder.
There's also modules in `/usr/lib/grub/powerpc-ieee1275/`.

I wrote up a list of modules I thought I needed:

```
normal
eval
read
test
test_blockarg
trig
true
```

I then added them to my `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES="normal eval read test test_blockarg trig true"
```

I did not find an entry for `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES` in the config file, so I had to do some searching to find out how. I want these modules to be added every time I generate the grub config file, which means putting them in the `00_header` portion of grub.

Then I recreated the configuration file:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

The modules were in the header and things worked perfectly on reboot.

If I had to guess: you probably only need the `test` module to enable `if` statements.